# compare 2 element of WS response with xpath in soapui

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui, assertion

I'm using `SoapUI` for testing and I need to compare two elements of the XML response.

For example, if I have an xml like this:

```
<book>
 <priceCzech>2</priceCzech>
 <priceIta>3</priceIta>
<book>
```

How can I use `XPATH` assertion to check that the value of priceIta and price Czech are equal?

I read `XPATH` explanation and I understood that typing the name of the element (that i consider a tag = priceCzech) let you perform some operation with operators

So why if I put not equal price and check it with (or without) slashes, the assertion give me valid?

```
//priceCzech = //priceIta
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this
**XPath Expression**
matches(//priceCzech,//priceIta)
**Expected result**
true
More guideline :[here](http://www.udsayshelloworld.com/2017/03/26/xpath-functions-soapui/)